# How to assign a specific ID for a radio buttons in ipywidgets

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I'm using ipywidgets library to create a radio buttons, for example:

```
   option_search = widgets.RadioButtons(
        options=parameter,
        disabled=False,
    )
```

I need to assign a specific ID name "test" for this instance to apply my css code :
I've tried some solutions but they are all not worked:

```
 option_search.add_class("test")
```

or

```
option_search.layout = widgets.Layout(id="test")
```

What should I do with this problem ? Thanks a lot